# Play audio from LocalStorage when refreshed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a favorites list of sounds. I can sorta get it to work but when I refresh the page the sound won't work when pressed. It will work again if I add another favorite to the list.

```
<div>
  <span>
 <a href="#/" id="Sound1" name="names" class="buttonsf" onClick="reply_click(event)">Sound1</a><a href="#/" class="fav">X</a></span>
 <span>
 <a href="#/" id="Sound2" name="names" class="buttonsf" onClick="reply_click(event)">Sound2</a><a href="#/" class="fav">X</a></span>
</div>
<div id="add">
//favorites get added here through append
</div>
```

javascript

```
function createListeners() 
{
 let names = document.getElementsByName("names");
 for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
 {
  let name = names[i];
  name.removeEventListener('click', playAudio);
  name.addEventListener('click', playAudio);
 }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => 
{
 createListeners();
});
//audio
function playAudio(e) 
{
 let el = e.currentTarget;
 var audio = new Audio();
 var src = "mp3/" + el.id + ".mp3";
 audio.src = src;
 audio.play();
 return audio;
}
```

More JS but this is for localStorage, doubt this is the problem

```
//favorited sound
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 var $ul = $('#add');
//get items from local storage
 if(localStorage.getItem('vkf-links'))
 {
 $ul.html(localStorage.getItem('vkf-links'));
 }
 $('.fav').click(function(e) 
 {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = $(this).prevAll().attr('id');
  $('#add').append('<span><a href="#/" id="' + x + '" name="names" class="buttonsf" onload="createListeners()">' + x + '</a><button id="removebtn" class="remove">x</button><span>');
  createListeners();
  //save changes to localstorage
  localStorage.setItem('vkf-links', $ul.html());
 });
 //remove item
 $("#add").on('click','#removebtn',function() 
 {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  //save changes to localstorage
  localStorage.setItem('vkf-links', $ul.html());
 });
});
```

(I changed the audio to a link for jsfiddle, it was originally "mp3/" + e.id + ".mp3")
https://jsfiddle.net/q15xoqp2/2/

Comment: this is weird it's not firing the DOMContentLoaded...

Comment: try `window.addEventListener('load', function() { createListeners(); });` instead of `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => { createListeners(); });`

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: reply_click is not defined` jsfiddle does not load local links, try using plnkr https://plnkr.co to reproduce issue

Comment: lol found it your missing a curly bracket https://codepen.io/sajrashid/pen/PEXPgB

Comment: @guest271314 oops, that part was supposed to be deleted

Comment: @Ivan86 That didn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `DOMContentLoaded` you are adding event listeners to all current elements named `'names'`.
In `$.ready` you add more of these elements.

Since jQuery 3 `ready` fires after your own DOMContentLoaded handlers (probably because they decided to defer `ready`).

This means that you will first add the listeners only to the initial ones, and then only add *localStored* items, which won't have the event attached to them.

A few possible fixes, from cleaner to dirtier:

- Add a single event listener that will delegate to all the elements named `"names"` during the whole document's life:

  ```js
  $(document).on('click', '[name="names"]', playAudio);
  ```

- Call your initial `createListeners` at the end of your `ready` handler:

  ```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //...
    $("#add").on('click','#removebtn',function() {
      //...
    });
    createListeners();
  }
  ```
- Call again `createListeners` after you append the localeStored items:

  ```js
   if(localStorage.getItem('vkf-links')){
     $ul.html(localStorage.getItem('vkf-links'));
     createListeners();
   }
  ```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q15xoqp2/3/)

Comment: I ended up using the second one and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JacobRidge though the first one is the cleanest, only one listener, no need to remove + add it every time.

Comment: Turns out I copied and pasted it wrong the first time, thought it didn't work.